Need kernel version string in ConditionPathExists of systemd unit file
Is there any way to get the version string of the running kernel into ConditionPathExists?
like
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=/opt/someapp/(uname-r)

I am aware that uname -r does not work here. But is there any feasible workaround?

I think there are probably several ways to do what you want.
Use a dependency instead of condition
First, you could replace your ConditionPathExists with a dependency on another service. If we create a service checkForKernelPath.service like this:
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=sh -c "test -f /opt/someapp/$(uname -r)"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

Then you can rewrite your existing unit like this:
[Unit]
Requires=checkForKernelPath.service
After=checkForKernelPath.service

checkForKernelPath.service will fail to start if the path doesn't exist, so your service unit won't start, either.
Have another unit responsible for starting your unit
Instead of an explicit dependency, create a new unit that starts your unit only if the condition is met:
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=sh -c "test -f /opt/someapp/$(uname -r) && systemctl start --no-block myservice.service"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

Use a generator
Write a generator to generate the unit when the system boots. Place something like this in /etc/systemd/system-generators/my-generator:
#!/bin/sh

normal_dir=$1
early_dir=${2:-$normal_dir}
late_dir=${3:-$normal_dir}

cat > "$normal_dir/example-generated-unit.service" <<EOF
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=/tmp/$(uname -r)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=touch /tmp/flagfile
EOF

Ensure it's executable and then either systemctl daemon-reload or just reboot. When this runs it will create /run/systemd/generator/example-generated-unit.service and (try to) start it.
We're use a here document in the script, so that $(uname -r) runs when the generator runs, and the resulting unit file contains a literal string.
